# Warnings from String interpolation

Tags: swift, swift4, string-interpolation

I've encountered a problem I can't solve myself. I have tried the Internet without any luck.

I'm still pretty new to Swift and coding, and right now following a guide helping me create an app.

Unfortunately, as I can understand, the app was written for Swift 3, and is giving me some issues since I'm using Swift 4.

I have to lines that gives me this warning:

> String interpolation produces a debug description for an optional value; did you mean to make this explicit?
>
> Use 'String(describing:)' to silence this warning    Fix
>
> Provide a default value to avoid this warning    Fix

However, when I click one of Xcode's solutions I get another problem.

If I use the first fix, the app crashes and I get the following message:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpected Segue Identifier;

If I use the second fix I have to assign a default value. And I don't know what this should be.

The whole passage of code is as follows.
It's the line starting with `guard let selectedMealCell` and the last one after `default:` that is causing the issues.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    
    switch(segue.identifier ?? "") {
    case "AddItem":
        os_log("Adding a new meal.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)

    case "ShowDetail":
        guard let mealDetailViewController = segue.destination as? MealViewController else {
            fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)")
        }
        
        guard let selectedMealCell = sender as? MealTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("Unexpected sender: \(sender)")
        }
        
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedMealCell) else {
            fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table")
        }
        
        let selectedMeal = meals[indexPath.row]
        mealDetailViewController.meal = selectedMeal
        
    default:
        fatalError("Unexpected Segue Identifier; \(segue.identifier)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Please never use `String(describing:)`, the message by Xcode is misleading. Instead, you should first unwrap the optional, then use interpolation or else.

Comment: I think you could write `fatalError("Unexpected sender: \(sender as Any)")`.

Comment: @EricAya can you provide more explanation as to why to not use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the first suggested fix worked for you.  It quieted the compile time warning, although admittedly `String(describing:)` is a weak solution.

In both cases, you need to unwrap the optional value. For the first case you should use:

```
guard let selectedMealCell = sender as? MealTableViewCell else {
    if let sender = sender {
        fatalError("Unexpected sender: \(sender))")
    } else {
        fatalError("sender is nil")
    }
}
```

and in the second case:

```
fatalError("Unexpected Segue Identifier; \(segue.identifier ?? "")")
```

Then you got a runtime error:

> "Unexpected Segue Identifier;"

That is telling you that your `switch` didn't match the first 2 cases and it ran the `default` case.  The crash is caused because your code is explicitly calling `fatalError`.  Your `segue.identifier` is apparently an empty string.

So your problem is actually in your Storyboard.  You need to assign identifiers to your segues.  Click on the segue arrows between your view controllers, and assign identifiers `"AddItem"` and `"ShowDetail"` to the proper segues.  The **segue identifier** is assigned in the *Attributes Inspector* on the right in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

If you are prepared to write an small extension to Optional, it can make the business of inserting the value of an optional variable less painful, and avoid having to write `optionalVar ?? ""` repeatedly:

Given:

```
extension Optional: CustomStringConvertible {

    public var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .some(let wrappedValue):
            return "\(wrappedValue)"
        default:
            return "<nil>"
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can write:

```
var optionalWithValue: String? = "Maybe"
var optionalWithoutValue: String?

print("optionalWithValue is \(optionalWithValue.description)")
print("optionalWithoutValue is \(optionalWithoutValue.description)")
```

which gives:

```
optionalWithValue is Maybe
optionalWithoutValue is <nil>
```

You can also write `print("value is \(anOptionalVariable)")` -- the `.description` is redundant since print() uses CustomStringConvertible.description anyway -- but although it works you still get the annoying compiler warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to automatically produce "nil" (or any other String) for nil values and for non-nil values use the `description` provided by `CustomStringConvertible`

```
extension String.StringInterpolation {
    mutating func appendInterpolation<T: CustomStringConvertible>(_ value: T?) {
        appendInterpolation(value ?? "nil" as CustomStringConvertible)
    }
}
```

For your own types you have to conform to `CustomStringConvertible` for this to work:

```
class MyClass: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "Whatever you want to print when you use MyClass in a string"
    }
}
```

With this set up, you can simply use your optionals the same way as any other type, without any compiler warnings.

```
var myClass: MyClass?
myClass = MyClass()
print("myClass is \(myClass)")
```